NetlifyでHonoをテストしたいが、エラーになる
以下のサイトで出ている手順にしたがって、Netlify上でサンプルコードを実行したいが、ローカルでのテスト実行でエラーになる。
https://hono-ja.pages.dev/docs/
何か他に必要な作業があるのか、教えていただければ助かります。
よろしくお願いします。
手順:

サンプルコードのインストール
$ npm create hono@latest


honoのインストール
$ npm install hono


テスト実行
$ netlify dev



エラー
◈ Failed to run Edge Function index:
TypeError: Import 'https://registry-staging.deno.com/@hono/hono/meta.json' failed: error sending request for url (https://registry-staging.deno.com/@hono/hono/meta.json): error trying to connect: dns error: failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known
    at file:///home/okuno/netlify/test/my-app/netlify/edge-functions/index.ts:1:22
    at async file:///home/okuno/netlify/test/my-app/.netlify/edge-functions-serve/dev.js:7:35 {
  code: "ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND"
}
TypeError: Import 'https://registry-staging.deno.com/@hono/hono/meta.json' failed: error sending request for url (https://registry-staging.deno.com/@hono/hono/meta.json): error trying to connect: dns error: failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known
    at file:///home/okuno/netlify/test/my-app/netlify/edge-functions/index.ts:1:22
    at async file:///home/okuno/.nvm/versions/node/v20.16.0/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/@netlify/edge-bundler/deno/config.ts:12:10 {
  code: "ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND"


他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？

コメントありがとうございます。
Qiitaでも同じ質問をしていました。
今後はマルチポストした場合には、その旨書いておきます。

解決しました。Denoをインストールする必要がありました。
以下のコマンドを実行した後に実行すると、期待通りの挙動となりました。
$ sudo snap install deno

